# How to determine if two binary trees are equal or different

Tags: binary-tree, nodes

The picture below is the case of different binary trees that can be made with 3 nodes.

[image]

But why is the following case not included in the number of cases?

[image]

Is it the same case as the third case from the left in the picture above? If so, I think the parent-child relationship will be different.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to determine how binary trees are equal to or different from each other.

Comment: Please provide the context for that picture. It is likely that the text that goes with it will give a hint why the author only presented trees rooted in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean 3 nodes. Your case is not included because the cases all use `A` as the root node, so it is easier to demonstrate the different possible combinations using always the same elements in the *same* order, i.e. `A` as root, then `B` ->  `C` on top and symmetrically `C` -> `B` at the bottom.

Using `B` or `C` as the root, you could achieve the same number of variations. This number can be computed using the following formula:

[image]

In this case, `n=3`, so `F(0)*F(2) + F(1)*F(1) + F(2)*F(0) = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5`
`F(0) = 1` (empty is considered one variation)
`F(1) = 1`
`F(2) = 2`

So in your picture, only one row is actually relevant if that is supposed to be a binary search tree. Also note that there is a difference between a binary tree and a binary *search* tree. From first article below:

> As we know, the BST is an ordered data structure that allows no
> duplicate values. However, Binary Tree allows values to be repeated
> twice or more. Furthermore, Binary Tree is unordered.

References
https://www.baeldung.com/cs/calculate-number-different-bst
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Using_graph_theory_concepts
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Binary_tree